# How to write a cypher query to find nodes tagged by specific tags?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Db structure:

```
(:Event)-[:IS_TAGGED_BY]->(:EventTag {value})
```

Comments for the structure:

- There are Event nodes
- There are EventTag nodes
- Tag nodes have a string property, called "value"
- Events may be tagged by tags via IS_TAGGED_BY outgoing rel

---

I need to write a query, that will return only those events, which are tagged by a specific set of tags.

There are may be two variations of such a query, which return:

1. Events, tagged by at least one of the specified tags (let's call it `findTaggedByAny`).
2. Events, tagged by all specified tags (let's call it `findTaggedByAll`).

I can write the `findTaggedByAny` query:

```
MATCH (et:EventTag)--(e:Event) WHERE et.value in {0} RETURN e
```

here {0} - is where the query parameter, containing a set of tag values, will be substituted.

So, after substitution the query will look like:

```
MATCH (et:EventTag)--(e:Event) WHERE et.value in ["tag1", "tag2"] RETURN e
```

But I have difficulties trying to implement the `findTaggedByAll` query, which also should take the same parameter and return events, tagged by all tags from the set. And it doesn't matter whether an event is tagged by any other tags or not.

Comment: So, you want to `RETURN` `:Event` nodes that are only connected to specified `:EventTag` nodes? ... or `:Event` nodes that are at a minimum connected to specified `:EventTag` nodes?  I.e., they could be also connected to unspecified `:EventTag` nodes.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Sorry, my question was unclear. They may be connected to any other tags, it doesn't matter. I modified my question to clarify this an other aspects of the issue.

Comment: Does `:Tag` = `:EventTag`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

1. If you want to get events that are connected to all tags in the DB, you can do an efficient "degree-ness" check, like this (assuming that an event is only connected at most once to a specific tag, and the `IS_TAGGED_BY` relationship is only used to connect events to tags):

   ```
   MATCH (t:EventTag)
   WITH COUNT(t) AS numTags
   MATCH (e:Event)
   WHERE SIZE((e)-[:IS_TAGGED_BY]->()) = numTags
   RETURN e;
   ```
2. If, instead, you want to get events that are tagged by *any* tag in a `tagList` parameter:

   ```
   MATCH (e:Event)-[:IS_TAGGED_BY]->(t:EventTag)
   WHERE t.value IN $tagList
   RETURN e;
   ```
3. If, instead, you want to get events that are tagged by *all* tags in a `tagList` parameter:

   ```
   MATCH (e:Event)-[:IS_TAGGED_BY]->(t:EventTag)
   WITH e, COLLECT(t.value) AS tagValues
   WHERE ALL(v IN tagValues WHERE v IN $tagList)
   RETURN e;
   ```

   Also, if it is relatively rare for an event to have that many tags, this longer query may actually be faster (by doing a degree-ness check before actually looking at the tags):

   ```
   MATCH (e:Event)
   WHERE SIZE((e)-[:IS_TAGGED_BY]->()) >= SIZE($tagList)
   MATCH (e)-[:IS_TAGGED_BY]->(t:EventTag)
   WITH e, COLLECT(t.value) AS tagValues
   WHERE ALL(v IN tagValues WHERE v IN $tagList)
   RETURN e;
   ```

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear. I don't want to check whether an event is connected to all tags, which are currently in db, or not. I pass a query parameter, containing a set of tags, which I interested in. I modified my question to clarify this an other aspects of the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code does almost fit my needs, the only change I made is related to the following line: `WHERE ALL(v IN tagValues WHERE v IN $tagList)`. I was need to change it to `WHERE all(tagValue IN $tagList WHERE tagValue IN tagValues)`. Otherwise it works not as findTaggedByAll, but as findTaggedByAllAndOnly.